# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии пользователем на пуш уведомление, он попадал в определённую область приложения?

Tags: xcode, swift, iphone

У меня приложение, в котором есть 5 вкладок (Tab Bar Controller). Среди этих пяти вкладок одна отвечает за вывод ленты событий пользователя (поставленные ему лайки, комментарии и прочее). Когда на сайте кто-то ставит пользователю лайк или коммент, то на телефон приходит пуш уведомление. Если приложение свёрнуто, то пользователь видит пуш уведомление и если он хочет его просмотреть полностью, он нажимает на пуш уведомление и после этого должно открыться моё приложение и в нём должна открыться именно вкладка событий. Как это можно настроить?

Comment: в самом уведомлении напишите куда надо отправлять пользователя, например /tab1/event1232342342 и исходя их этого парсите и открывайте нужный контроллер

Comment: Т.е. это с сервера надо отправлять что должно открываться?

Comment: ага, именно так

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko а как примерно тогда будет выглядеть пуш, который отправляется с сервера? Не совсем пойму какой ключ для этого надо использовать.

Comment: вот документация, там где в примере "acme" можете вписывать, что вам хочется https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1

Comment: А через приложение нельзя это как-то задать? У меня только одна эта вкладка всегда должна открываться при нажатии на пуш.

Comment: тогда просто когда получаете уведомление открывайте сразу нужный экран https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko но мне нужно чтобы нужный экран открывался только если пользователь нажмёт на пуш. Или это оно и есть?

Comment: ну когда приходит уведомление запоминайте время, и если приложение стало активным в течение, например 2 секунд после этого, значит пользователь нажал на пуш

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko спасибо